# What does it mean to verbalize a function?

Tags: r, function, pipe, tidyverse

I am reading [Create Awesome LaTeX Table with knitr::kable and kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf), a vignette of the [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/index.html) package.

At page 3 it says that kableExtra:

> imports the pipe %>% symbol from magrittr and verbalizes all the functions, so basically you can add “layers” to a kable output in a way that is similar with ggplot2 and plotly.

What does it mean "to verbalize a function"?

Comment: I think they just mean kable works like ggplot, as in add details via pipe, `do this pipe do that pipe do etc.` do is a verb(function).

Comment: In this context, it means to write functions in a way that follows the tidyverse way of writing functions. For example, {dplyr} functions are often referred to as verbs, e.g. `filter()` or `select()`. Each function does one specific task, and functions can be chained together using the pipe operator. You can keep adding more layers or performing more tasks without having to save intermediate variables, since the output format remains the same as the input format with this approach.

Comment: I've never read this term before, and I'm not sure if it was the right one to use. In dplyr functions are often named as verbs, and when these are used with the pipe `%>%` code often looks like a nice sentence if you pronounce `%>%` as "and then". this might be what the author meant. In any case they're talking more about magrittr than kableExtra here, especially since kableExtra's functions seem not to be named as verbs.

Comment: One step further: object (function) naming is one of the [two hard things in computer science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19836). Some choose to name their functions in an imperative (verb) manner, others choose a more descriptive manner, etc. It's similar to the debate between snake_case, TitleCase, and pascalCase: all are liked by some, nobody likes all, and none of them are truly better than the others (in other than subjective terms).